# python - Pass/Sending return variables from one function to another

Tags: python, function

I was trying to pass two variables returned from one function to the next function but but I'm not really understanding what am I missing, i always get the error -

```
TypeError: Function2() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

My Code:

```
Function1(arg1, arg2):
# This two args to this function are taken from the user and some work is done here and this function will return two things as output (my_list1 is a list) - 
return my_list1, count

Function2 (argg1, argg2):
# This function will get the first and second argument from the previous function (Function1)

def main():
                Function1(list1, count1)
                myfinal_list, final_count = Function1()
                Function2(myfinal_list, final_count)

if __name__== "__main__":
        main()
```

How can I achieve this? What would I have to do to make sure data from the first function will be sent to the second function?
Thank you!

Comment: Why are you calling again `Function1()` without any arguments? Do `myfinal_list, final_count = Function1(list1, count1)`

Comment: Understood the logic behind it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def main():        
    myfinal_list, final_count = Function1(list1, count1)
    Function2(myfinal_list, final_count)
```

Since this sentence `myfinal_list, final_count = Function1()` will give you an error because you are calling a `Funcion1` with no arguments (while 2 are expected).

Comment: so that means, `Function1(list1, count1)` will have values that were returned and get's assigned to `myfinal_list, final_count` ?

Comment: Thank you Pablo. Working as expected. Understood the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close, but just missing one part:

In short, you have to include the arguments when calling the function. For instance, in the line: `myfinal_list, final_count = Function1()` you don't call either argument.

Accordingly, `main()` should be rewritten as follows:

```
def main():
    myfinal_list, final_count = Function1(list1, count1)
    Function2(myfinal_list, final_count)
```

Comment: Thanks Darcy, got it!